# Allowed memory size exhausted with Propel2 custom query

Tags: php, mysql, propel2

(*updates at bottom*)

I'm trying to get the latest entry in my table called "VersionHistory", and since the ID is set to auto increment, I was trying to get the max id. Trying to stay away from sorting the whole table in descending order and taking the top as I want to minimize the computation required for this query as the table grows, and this table will probably get pretty huge fast.

```
class VersionHistoryQuery extends BaseVersionHistoryQuery {
    public function getLatestVersion() {
        return $this
            ->withColumn('MAX(version_history.id)')
            ->limit(1);
    }
}
```

I'm calling the function in my VersionHistory constructor as below:

```
class VersionHistory extends BaseVersionHistory {
    public function __construct($backupPath = "") {
        $lastVersion = VersionHistoryQuery::create()
            ->getLatestVersion()
            ->find();
        $lastVersion->setBackupPath("backup/" . $backupPath);
        $lastVersion->save();
        parent::setImportedAt(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    }    
}
```

This outputs a "Allowed memory size exhausted" error in php. Any idea why? Commenting out the query in the VersionHistory constructor fixes the error, so it's somewhere in the query. I tried setting up a custom query following the instructions here: http://propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html#using-custom-sql. But I couldn't get that to work. Running:

```
SELECT * FROM version_history WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM version_history)
```

From MySQL workbench works fine and quickly.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

## What I tried

Updated the code to:

```
    public function getLatestVersion() {
        return $this
        ->orderById('desc')
        ->findOne();
    }
```

Still get the same memory allocation error.

---

Updated the code to:

```
        $lastVersion = VersionHistoryQuery::create()
        ->orderById('desc')
        ->findOne();
```

Removed the custom function, turned on propel debug mode, it outputs that this query is run:

```
[2015-10-11 17:26:54] shop_reporting_db.INFO: SELECT `version_history`.`id`, `version_history`.`imported_at`, `version_history`.`backup_path` FROM `version_history` ORDER BY `version_history`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1 [] []
```

Still runs into a memory overflow.

Comment: It looks as though `propel is doing the correct query and you memory issues are elsewhere.`

Comment: I thought so too, but removing query removes all issues. It's only when I add in the query that any issues occur.

Comment: what is the table definition? are there proper indexes on the field?

Comment: Yup, they are! It's weird because I can run other queries on it, I think that it's just I was writing with Propel incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Thats all:

```
SELECT * FROM version_history ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The reason why I don't want to use that is because I know that the table will get very large as time goes on, so I want to make sure that it's efficient, which is why I was using

    SELECT * FROM version_history WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM version_history)

but the question is how to execute this through propel.

Comment: Thats the best way : put "EXPLAIN " before the query and you see that mySQL only reads ONE row. It can do this with the Primary Key on the field id

Comment: Didn't know that either. Thanks. I updated it to:

         public function getLatestVersion() {
      return $this
      ->orderById('desc')
      ->findOne();
     }

still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, [withColumn](http://propelorm.org/Propel/reference/model-criteria.html) does the following:

> Propel adds the 'with' column to the SELECT clause of the query, and
>   uses the second argument of the withColumn() call as a column alias.

So, it looks like you are actually querying every row in the table, and also every row is querying the max ID.

I don't know anything about propel (except what I just googled), but it looks like you need a different way to specify your where condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your raw SQL and your Propel Query are different / not equivalent.

In the propel query merely added a column, whereas is your raw SQL your actually have two queries with one being a sub-query to the other.

So you need to do the equivalent in Propel:

```
$lastVersionID = VersionHistoryQuery::create()
    ->withColumn('MAX(id)', 'LastVersionID')
    ->select('LastVersionID')
    ->findOne();

$lastVersion = VersionHistoryQuery::create()
    ->filterByVersionHistory($lastVersionID)
    ->find();
```

Note the `->select('LatestVersionID')` since you only need a scalar value and not an entire object, as well as the virtual column (alias in SQL) using `withColumn()`

Comment: Qiniso, while that is correct, I don't think that solves the problem. I believe the root issue is that the VersionHistory constructor is calling itself recursively through the find method within the constructor. What do you think?